# How to fit YouTube player to available browser window?

Tags: google-chrome, display-resolution, youtube

Youtube video player has changed size overnight in Chrome and I can't seem to fit it to available screen anymore. Relevant info:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Chrome v68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Screen: FHD 1920x1080
- Resolution: 1368x768 (16:9)
- Chrome Zoom: 125%

[image]

I have tried every zoom and resolution, can't seem to fit the player to available screen.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Youtube Enhancer it is available for Firefox as well. For Chrome just click [this link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/magic-enhancer-for-youtub/koiaokdomkpjdgniimnkhgbilbjgpeak/related?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)

You'll see extra buttons like *Cinema Mode*, *Fill In*, etc.

[image: youtube]